# How to finish this edit war?

Tags: discussion, flags, edits, declined-flags

[How can I extract list from list in prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206743/how-can-i-pppp-eeeee#27206743)

First, I thought I should flag it, but then I get the message that my last flag was declined. Also, there is no item fit for closing.

Comment: I believe that an edit war is automatically flagged to the moderators. This has been asked before on this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Not really a duplicate, the other concerns changing one legit question to another equally legit question. This here, was from one to completely another language, and then even to some political issue.

Comment: True, but it does verify what I've thought all along -- that an edit war will automatically trigger moderate action, and that was the type of answer that I was looking for which I believe is the main answer to this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: So then, the best to do in that situation seems to revert twice.

Comment: Yes, keep reverting it until a moderator locks it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Assuming you were serious, the correct course of action is to flag the question and walk away.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: this is ideally true, but what if the flag is declined, as it appears that his was.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: One is for sure: Flagging does not work. I have had flags that were "deemed useful" 5 days later.

Comment: This was a horrible write-my-code-for-me question to begin with.  Unfortunately now I can't downvote it for having no effort, because the lock prevents voting.